# Struggling with json array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json

Ive changed a json object recieved from an api and changed it to an array using $.makeArray and now im struggling to get values from this array. Im wanting temp_c and value within weather desc. A print out of the array is below.

```
[
Object
data: Object
current_condition: Array[1]
0: Object
cloudcover: "50"
humidity: "72"
observation_time: "10:25 AM"
precipMM: "0.1"
pressure: "1005"
temp_C: "13"
temp_F: "55"
visibility: "10"
weatherCode: "122"
 weatherDesc: Array[1]
 0: Object
  value: "Overcast"
__proto__: Object
length: 1
__proto__: Array[0]
weatherIconUrl: Array[1]
winddir16Point: "SSW"
winddirDegree: "210"
windspeedKmph: "19"
windspeedMiles: "12"
__proto__: Object
length: 1
__proto__: Array[0]
request: Array[1]
__proto__: Object
__proto__: Object
```

Comment: can you post the raw JSON instead?

Comment: what is it that you require here ?

Comment: can you post the JavaScript code?

Answer (score 0):

You could try:

`alert(yourObject.temp_C);`

And

`alert(yourObject.weatherDesc.value);`

You wouldn't need to convert it to an array :)

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to transform the object into an array, just access the properties you need:

```
var o = object_retrieved_from_api;
o.temp_c;
o.weatherDesc[0].value;
```

If you convert it into an array, just have to index first object in array:

```
var a = $.makeArray(object_retrieved_from_api);
a[0].temp_c;
a[0].weatherDesc[0].value;
```

Answer (score 0):

The whole point of JSON is that it is already a Javascript object, so you don't need any complex parsing logic in order to get the data out. Try out the following code and you'll see how easy it is to get data from a JSON web service.

```
$.getJSON('your JSON URL here', function(data) {

  $.each(data.current_condition, function() {
    alert(this.temp_C + "C " + this.weatherDesc[0].value);
  });

});
```